# AVPlayer with Streaming videos or NSFileHandle

Tags: ios, streaming, avplayer, nsfilehandle

In my app I need to play multiple videos one after another. Currently, I am streaming the videos using `AVPlayer` but its seems very laggy, the videos freeze quite often. I'm wondering if downloading the files with `NSFileHandle` will provide a better user experience with less lagging. BUT, Im worried about memory issues.

Does anyone have any recommendations in which way is more efficient? Or, for example, how snapchat plays such a large number of videos so smoothly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To control the playback of assets, you use an AVPlayer object. During playback, you can use an AVPlayerItem instance to manage the presentation state of an asset as a whole, and an AVPlayerItemTrack object to manage the presentation state of an individual track. To display video, you use an AVPlayerLayer object.
[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW2)